# Injectivity of a function of several variables

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives

Let $f: \Bbb{R}^n \rightarrow \Bbb{R}^n$ be defined as

$f(x) = x||x||^2$ for $x \in \Bbb{R}^n$.

I need to prove or disprove the following statement:

$f$ is one-one.

I think it is a wrong statement as if I take $n = 2$ then determinant of $Df(0) = 0$ which means it is not one-one in any neighbourhood of $(0,0)$.

Hence the given statement is false.

But the answer sheet of my book says it is correct.

Please confirm

Comment: If the determinant is not $0$, then the function is injective in a neighborhood. But this does not imply that if it *is* $0$, then it's not injective. If I'm French, then I'm European. But if I'm not French, I might still be European...

Comment: Actually, It is written in my class notes that that $f$ is 1-1 in a neighbourhood iff determinant is non-zero

Comment: Seems like it is wrong

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rewrite your function as $$f(x) = u(x) \| x\|^3,$$ where $u(x)$ is the unit vector in the direction of $x.$ For $f(x) = f(y),$ we must have $u(x) = u(y)$ and $\|x\| = \|y\|,$ so $x=y.$

Comment: Could you tell what's wrong in my argument?

Comment: Isn't it true that if $Df(x) = 0$ then $f$ is not one-one in any neighbourhood of $x$?

Comment: @Gitika Clearly it is not true in general, given the example I gave in my answer above.

Comment: How will we write this if $x$ is $0$?

Comment: @Gitika good question: when $x=0,$ then $f(x) = 0.$ You can use any direction, but the norm $0$ determines where your point goes.

Answer (score 3):

To gain some intuition for why your reasoning is false, consider $f\colon 
\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x) = x^3$ (notice the similarity with your function.) It is easy to see that $f'(0) = 0$ but the point $0$ is neither a local min nor a local max and we know that $f$ is strictly increasing so it is injective.

Try to prove directly from the definition that your function is injective, i.e., that $f(y) = f(z)$ implies $y = z$.

Comment: Okay..so for n=1, we are getting that it is injective. But that doesn't imply that every function of that form will be injective

Comment: I am still not getting what is the problem with my example

Comment: "I am still not getting what is the problem with my example" you said that $Df(0)=0$ implies $f$ is not one-to-one. What don't you get about the fact that this example shows that that's false?

Comment: @Gitika The Jacobian determinant is strictly positive everywhere but 0. Thus $f$ is locally invertible on $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus \left\{0\right\}$. It is easy to see that if $f(z) = 0$ then $z =0$ so we have injectivity at the origin. Why should the Jacobian determinant being zero at 0 imply it is not injective at that point?